# WinAPI timer don't send WM_TIMER event

Tags: winapi, timer

I'm workin at very simple program that animate shape movement. Animation can be switched to on/off mode using right mouse button. I'm creating timer in window procedure and waiting for WM_TIMER event. But after creating timer (return value of SetTimer is 1) WM_TIMER case never reaching (i'm set break point at next line to detect it).
My window procedure:

```
fn CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) -> LRESULT {

    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    RECT win;
    GetClientRect(hWnd, &win);
    int w = win.right - win.left;
    int h = win.bottom - win.top;

    static COLORREF shape_color = RGB(0, 255, 255);

    static int x = 50, y = 50;
    static int r = 40;

    int step = 50;
    static bool animation = false;

    switch (message) {

    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:

        GetColorDlg(hWnd, shape_color);
        break;

    case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:

        animation = !animation;
        if (animation) {
            timer_id = SetTimer(hWnd, 1, 500, NULL);
        }
        else {
            KillTimer(hWnd, timer_id);
        }
        break;

    case WM_TIMER:
        ++x_offset;
        y_offset = sin(x_offset) * 20;

    case WM_KEYDOWN: {

        if (!animation) {
            switch (wParam) {
            case VK_UP:
                y -= step;
                break;
            case VK_DOWN:
                y += step;
                break;
            case VK_LEFT:
                x -= step;
                break;
            case VK_RIGHT:
                x += step;
                break;
            }
        }

        y += y_offset;
        x += x_offset;

        x = x + r > w ? w - r : x - r < 0 ? r : x;
        y = y + r > h ? h - r : y - r < 0 ? r : y;

        RECT invalid_area;
        invalid_area.top = y + r;
        invalid_area.left = x - r;
        invalid_area.bottom = y - r;
        invalid_area.right = x + r;
        InvalidateRect(hWnd, &invalid_area, true);
        break;

    }

    case WM_SIZE: {

        if (x + r > w)
            x = w - r;

        if (y + r > h)
            y = h - r;

        break;

    }

    case WM_PAINT: {

        //HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);

        HBRUSH shape_brush = CreateSolidBrush(shape_color);
        HPEN   shape_pen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 2, RGB(0, 0, 0));

        SelectObject(hdc, shape_pen);
        SelectObject(hdc, shape_brush);

        Circle(hdc, x, y, r);

        DeleteObject(shape_pen);
        DeleteObject(shape_brush);
        DeleteObject(hdc);
        ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
        //EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;

    }

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `WM_PAINT` handler you're not calling `BeginPaint` / `EndPaint`, which means your window will always remain marked as invalid. This will generate a continuous stream of `WM_PAINT` messages, and this stops your timer from working because `WM_TIMER` messages are only generated when the message queue is empty.

See [*If my WM_TIMER handler takes longer than the timer period, will my queue fill up with WM_TIMER messages?*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/12/04/10577881.aspx) for the basic algorithm that controls when `WM_TIMER` messages are generated.

Comment: Thanks! It working, but now i have got a new problem - my circle remains a trail after moving. Looks like `InvalidateRect` are ignored. How to solve it?

Comment: Technically, `WM_PAINT` is the same as `WM_TIMER` (or `WM_MOUSEMOVE`). Neither is generated, if there are messages in the queue. Of the low-priority messages, `WM_TIMER` is returned only, if no other low-priority message needs to be generated. See [If my WM_TIMER handler takes longer than the timer period, will my queue fill up with WM_TIMER messages?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/12/04/10577881.aspx) for the basic algorithm.

Comment: @IInspectable Yes very true, the important point however is that `WM_PAINT` is higher priority than `WM_TIMER` and as long as a window region remains marked for painting no timer messages will ever be generated. Nice ONT link, I will add that to the answer.

Comment: @iRomul You're responsible for erasing the background if you want to "remove" something from the display, e.g. by using `FillRect` to draw over it.